# Samsung download mode adb command

Tags: android, adb, samsung-mobile

The command `adb reboot download` puts the device in the download mode,but I would like to reboot my device to the previous screen mode,where the user can select between,download mode,unlocking bootloader,like in this image:
[image: This is the desired state].
Right now,using the known `adb reboot download` command,lead directly to the inner screen,the actual download mode,as in this screen:
[image]